# The suggested edit queue needs to be clearer if it's a question or answer

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, user-interface

Both [@slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm) and I managed to vote to approve [this suggested edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34541), not realizing it was fixing broken code in the *question* as opposed to an *answer*. (Faheem Mitha rejected, after I admitted my mistake in chat and asked for reject votes). Of course, I went ahead and rolled back right after it was approved…

We'd like answers on the site to be free of errors, like the missing `$`, and to promote best practices, like quoting. So I think we want to continue approving suggested edits similar to that for answers.

However, those mistakes happened to be the problem the OP was experiencing. Fixing the code in the question lead to it being "Hey, why doesn't this [working code] work?", leaving the question useless for the OP, and nonsensical to the rest of us.

It is possible to tell them apart on that screen, by looking at the very bottom, but it's easy to miss. (Examples from SO):

[image: bottom of an answer] **vs.** [image: bottom of a question]

AFAIK, the only difference is the light-gray text, hidden at the bottom, saying "answered" or "asked". (I think the line-wrapping difference is only due to the number of tags.)

Comment: Relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179398/213575 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150142/213575. There's another for showing if the edit is on a question/answer but I didn't find it.